# jquery javascript: take action when radio button is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I have the following radio buttons, none of which is checked by default.

```
<input type="radio" name="location" value="0" /> home
<input type="radio" name="location" value="1" /> work
<input type="radio" name="location" value="2" /> school
```

How do I detect when either of them is checked. I'm looking for something like click, but it's not working

```
$("input[name=location]").click(function(){
    alert("selected");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine for me. Are you referencing well the jquery library?

Comment: It looks like it was a bug with something above this line, and it messed up the whole javascript below it.

Answer (score 14):

```
$('input[name=location]').change(function(){
    alert(this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try surrounding the code with below lines

```
$(document).ready(function(){

}
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you treid the onChange event?

```
$("input[name=location]").bind('change', function(){
    alert("selected");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("input[name=location]").bind('change', function(){
   alert("Hello!"); 
  }); 
});
```